# How to load related entities but with explicit loading?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

What is the equivalent for the following but with explicit loading?

```cs
var movie = await context
          .Movies
          .AsNoTracking()
          .Include(m => m.Genres)
          .Include(m => m.CinemaHalls)
              .ThenInclude(ch => ch.Cinema)
          .Include(m => m.MovieActors)
              .ThenInclude(ma => ma.Actor)
          .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
```

**My partial attempt:**

```cs
var movie = await context
               .Movies
               .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

if (movie is null) return;

await context.Entry(movie).Collection(m => m.Genres).LoadAsync();
await context.Entry(movie).Collection(m => m.CinemaHalls).LoadAsync();
await context.Entry(movie).Collection(m => m.MovieActors).LoadAsync();
```

I don't know how to load `Actor` of `MovieActors` and `Cinema` of `CinemaHalls`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.

```cs
foreach (var ch in movie.CinemaHalls)
     await context.Entry(ch).Reference(_ => _.Cinema).LoadAsync();
foreach (var ma in movie.MovieActors)
     await context.Entry(ma).Reference(_ => _.Actor).LoadAsync();
```

Comment: It is inefficient due to multiple roundtrips.